# Setting CSS Media Type Inline

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-type

I am producing a standalone HTML document under the constraint that the document has to be exactly one file. I would like to use CSS to make sure that links in the document are visible and discoverable (probably blue with underlines) when viewed in a browser, but to vanish most of that formatting when the document is printed.

Is this possible with just a `<style>` block?

Is it possible to get what I want with JavaScript jiggery-pokery?

Comment: `jiggery-pokery` is not a technical term.  Please define.  (:

Comment: I'm using 'jiggery-pokery' here as a synonym for 'klu[d]?ge'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use @media or @import in a `<style>` block and set styles specific to the media type.

Read more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

```
@media print {
  /* print styles */
  a {color:#333}
}
@media screen {
  /* screen only styles */
  a {border-bottom:1px solid blue}
}
/* general styles here */
```